# Multiple operation with Undo function in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsundomanager

I have a function for undo who works good. My app is a photo editor with multiple effect. When i add multiple effect to my photo and i undo all this effect, it works very good BUT when i want add again a filter/effect and i want undo again it don't work. I mean my undo function work only one time.

Can someone tell me why it work only one time ?

there is my function who work :

```
    - (void)updateImage:(UIImage*)Images {

        [undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateImage:) object:Images];

        _imageView.image = Images;

    }

    - (void)pushedUndoBtn:(id)sender
    {
       [undoManager undo];
    }
```

There is how i reference my undo manager :

```
    @implementation _CLImageEditorViewController
    {

        NSUndoManager * undoManager;

    } 

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];

    }
```

Comment: How your undoManager is stored in your class? Do you keep a strong reference to it?

Comment: i added more code of how i reference. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the old image (`_imageView.image`) to `-registerUndoWithTarget:selector:object:`, not the new image (`Images`). You want the undo operation to invoke `-updateImage:` with the old image to restore the old state. So:

```
    [undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateImage:) object:_imageView.image];
```

Comment: i try to explain with my basic english. Actually i can undo, it work but when i add again a filter and i undo again, it doesn't work. i can click on undo button only one time. After i don't work.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?